# objective c regular expression for full name

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I want to validate a string in objective C based on following rules:

1) No numbers and special characters allowed.

2) String should not start with a space.

3) String should not end with a space.

4) Any number of words are allowed in string.

5) Only one space is allowed between two consecutive words.

Currently I am using following code:

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"[A-Za-z]+[[\\s][A-Za-z]+]*";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
bool isCheckStringValid = [nameTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
```

However it doesn't satisfy 3rd and 5th fules. I've been trying this for an hour but no luck. Could anybody suggest me correct regular expression? Thanks.

Comment: try ^[A-Za-z]+([\s][A-Za-z]+)*$

Comment: You're making a huge assumption that a person's full name is only two sets of 'normal' characters separated by a space... There are many cultures where full names are more than two words, and many where special characters are used (assuming your 'special characters' includes things like üøéî etc.)

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know objective-c syntax, but a regex like this one should work:

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:\\s[A-Za-z]+)*$
```

Comment: this is usefull just in english

Comment: @yatanadam: You're right, but I just re-use OP's regex with correction.

Answer (score -1):

I had two input types and I had to prevent numbers and different character. I solved my problem by using this regex expression "[A-Za-z]+[[\s][A-Za-z ]+]$"

Comment: This does not answer the original question

Comment: No, I had my problem which is similar to original question and my problem was solved with this solution.